# parametric equation of the circle in polar form with center different from origin

Tags: calculus, geometry, algebra-precalculus

To find the parametric equation of the circle in polar form of radius $1$ with center $(-1,-1)$ where we start at the point $(-1,0)$ at $\theta = 0$ and travel counterclockwise up to $\theta = 2 \pi$.

I have found the following:

$$x = -1 + \sin(\theta), y = -1 + \cos(\theta).$$ Is the parametrization correct?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, indeed
$$
x^2+y^2=(-1+\sin(\theta))^2+(-1+\cos(\theta))^2=3-2\sin(\theta)-2\cos(\theta)
$$
and knowing that $\sin(\theta)=x+1$ and $\cos(\theta)=y+1$, you get
$$
x^2+y^2=-2x-2y-1
$$
i.e.,
$$
x^2+2x+1-1+y^2+2y+1-1=-1
$$
or
$$
(x+1)^2+(y+1)^2=1
$$
which is the cartesian equation of the circumference you want to parameterize.

---

In general, applying the same argument, you can prove that a parameterization of the circumference with center $(x_C,y_C)$ and radius $R$ is
$$
\begin{cases}
x=x_C+R\sin(\theta)\\
y=y_C+R\cos(\theta)\\
\end{cases}
$$
with $\theta\in [0,2\pi)$ (or any other interval of the same amplitude).
Note that also
$$
\begin{cases}
x=x_C+R\cos(\theta)\\
y=y_C+R\sin(\theta)\\
\end{cases}
$$
is a parameterization of the same cirumference, but with a different starting point.